# scrollable picturebox c# .net stop flickering using doublebufferring

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox, doublebuffered

I create a scrollable picturebox referring this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll.aspx).

It works fine. But image is flickering when I scrolling.

Windows forms has DoubleBuffered property. But picturebox haven't. I think if I can use DoubleBuffered on picturebox then might my problem solved.

Please help to overcome this problem

Thank You 
yohan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PictureBox is already double-buffered

check [Flicker-free painting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/aaed00ce-4bc9-424e-8c05-c30213171c2c)

also [HOW TO AVOID FLICKERING OF FORMS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/8f275e35-0807-459f-a5b6-fcc4455a3ca6)